# ¿Es correcto usar "por" en "¿por cuánto tiempo?"?

Tags: gramática, preposiciones

Querría saber si se considera válido el empleo de "por" en las siguientes frases:

> ¿**Por** cuánto tiempo has estado aprendiendo español? He estado aprendiendo español **por** tres meses.

Yo personalmente la quitaría de ambas, me parece un calco del inglés "for", pero un amigo peruano mío insiste en que le resultan más correctas y naturales las versiones con la palabra "por".

La RAE no parece mencionar alguna acepción de la palabra "por" que tenga algo que ver con una duración, y yo la reemplazaría por "durante" aunque tampoco me resultarían extrañas esas frases:

> ¿Cuánto tiempo has estado aprendiendo español? He estado aprendiendo español tres meses.

¿Qué pensáis al respecto? ¿El uso de "por" en esas frases os parece correcto? ¿Si no, dejaríais esas frases tal cual, o les añadiríais la preposición "durante"?

Answer (score 3):

Según [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/por-con-valor-temporal-3370/), que cita la Nueva Gramática, el uso de "por" con valor temporal es correcto:

> Según la Nueva gramática académica, aunque este uso de *por* con el sentido de *durante* es tildado por algunos de anglicismo, está documentado en español desde la Edad Media y puede considerarse apropiado.

La versión sin "por" puede resultar más natural, como así también otras frases temporales del tipo:

- ¿Cuánto tiempo hace que estás aprendiendo español?
- ¿Desde cuándo hace que estás aprendiendo español?